# How to send a PUT request with multiple layers of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

I need to send a Json "PUT" request to a API. I am quite new to Json encoding, so it's probably an easy one for you.

The Json looks like this..:

```
OrderDto {
Version (integer, optional),
IsDeactivated (boolean, optional, read only),
FiscalSetupId (integer, optional, read only),
CreatedAt (string, optional, read only),
CreatedBy (integer, optional, read only),
PartnerId (integer, optional),
OurReference (string, optional),
YourReference (string, optional),
ContextType (string, optional),
Address (AddressDto, optional),
DeliveryAddress (AddressDto, optional),
DeliveryNote (string, optional),
OrderNumber (integer, optional),
DateDays (integer, optional),
DeliveryDateDays (integer, optional),
CurrencyAbbreviation (string, optional),
OfferReportLayoutId (integer, optional),
DeliveryReportLayoutId (integer, optional),
InvoiceReportLayoutId (integer, optional),
ConfirmationReportLayoutId (integer, optional),
OfferReportLayoutName (string, optional),
DeliveryReportLayoutName (string, optional),
InvoiceReportLayoutName (string, optional),
ConfirmationReportLayoutName (string, optional),
InternalNote (string, optional),
TermsOfPayment (TermsOfPaymentDto, optional),
Culture (string, optional),
ProjectId (integer, optional),
ResponsibleId (integer, optional),
ResponsibleName (string, optional),
InvoiceEmail (string, optional),
PartnerAccountNumber (string, optional),
PartnerName (string, optional),
PartnerNote (string, optional),
PartnerPhoneNumber (string, optional),
PartnerType (string, optional),
Summary (OrderSummaryDto, optional),
OrderInvoiceNumbers (Array[integer], optional),
DepartmentId (integer, optional),
DepartmentDescription (string, optional),
BearerId (integer, optional),
BearerDescription (string, optional),
PurposeId (integer, optional),
PurposeDescription (string, optional),
IsHeaderReadOnly (boolean, optional),
OrderStatusId (integer, optional),
OrderStatusName (string, optional),
OrderStatusColor (string, optional),
ProjectDescription (string, optional),
ProjectNumber (integer, optional),
OrderDeliveryStatus (string, optional),
CultureDisplayName (string, optional, read only),
Id (integer, optional)
}
```

According to the API, the "OrderDto" is required on my request.

Here is my Curl/php:

```
$url="api-site-url"; //I am aware that the url is missing :)
$post_data=array('OrderDto'=>array('OurReference' => 'Faktureret'));
$createJSONData=json_encode($post_data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
                'APIKEY:  xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx'
          ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $createJSONData);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        print "Error: " . curl_error($ch);  
        } else {
        // Show me the result

        curl_close($ch);


        $obj=json_decode($data, true);
        print_r($obj);

        }
```

I am getting a error caused by a JSON error. What is your suggestions ?

Comment: The OrderDto is not a proper php construct for generating the JSON format. The supplied structure looks like instructions to the programmer as to what is required for each value.

Comment: I know, i am just trying to understand how i 'PUT' information to an array inside a array.

Comment: When i try to run the script on requestb.in i get the following Json: {"OrderDto":{"OurReference":"Faktureret"}} which should be correct, right ?